# Update and calculate nutritional value on dropdown change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've found something really similar to what I need to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/k3edG/3/

However I need to update the value depending on dropdown boxes. I've added the dropdowns but unsure how to get the correct values when the correct dropdown is changed. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

My JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1gvsezxx/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.options').on('change', 'input', function() {
        var $self = $(this);
        var inputType = $self.attr('type');

        if (inputType == 'radio') {
            $self.parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        } else if (inputType == 'checkbox') {
            $self.parent('li').toggleClass('active');
        }
        runUpdate();
    });

});

function runUpdate() {
    // get the sum of the elements
    var calories = $(".caloriesSum", '.active').sum();
    var fat = $(".fatSum", '.active').sum();
    var satfat = $(".satfatSum", '.active').sum();
    var carbs = $(".carbsSum", '.active').sum();
    var protein = $(".proteinSum", '.active').sum();
    var sodium = $(".sodiumSum", '.active').sum();
    var chloresterol = $(".chloesterolSum", '.active').sum();

    // update the total
    $("#totalCalories").text(+calories.toString());
    $("#totalFat").text(+fat.toString());
    $("#totalSatFat").text(+satfat.toString());
    $("#totalCarbs").text(+carbs.toString());
    $("#totalProtein").text(+protein.toString());
    $("#totalSodium").text(+sodium.toString());
    $("#totalChloresterol").text(+chloresterol.toString());
}
```

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add something like this

```
$(function() {
    $("#input-option227").change(function() {
        //To get the selected option use this code here -> $('option:selected', this).text();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes on your code, so please carefully study my modifications:

**HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post" id="nutform" onsubmit="return false;">
  <h4>Select Your Protein</h4>

  <div class="options">
    <select name="option[227]" id="input-option227" class="form-control">
      <option value="0"> --- Please Select --- </option>
      <option value="17">Herb Turkey</option>
      <option value="18">Moroccan Mince</option>
      <option value="19">Cajun Chicken</option>
    </select>

    <div id="HerbTurkey" data-option-id="17" class="nutritionInfo">
      <span class="caloriesSum">280</span>
      <span class="fatSum">6</span>
      <span class="satfatSum">0</span>
      <span class="carbsSum">44</span>
      <span class="proteinSum">8</span>
      <span class="sodiumSum">340</span>
      <span class="chloesterolSum">0</span>
    </div>

    <div id="MoroccanMince" data-option-id="18" class="nutritionInfo">
      <span class="caloriesSum">290</span>
      <span class="fatSum">6</span>
      <span class="satfatSum">2</span>
      <span class="carbsSum">49</span>
      <span class="proteinSum">9</span>
      <span class="sodiumSum">770</span>
      <span class="chloesterolSum">0</span>
    </div>

    <div id="CajunChicken" data-option-id="19" class="nutritionInfo">
      <span class="caloriesSum">265</span>
      <span class="fatSum">5</span>
      <span class="satfatSum">1</span>
      <span class="carbsSum">33</span>
      <span class="proteinSum">63</span>
      <span class="sodiumSum">12</span>
      <span class="chloesterolSum">6</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h4>Select Your Carbs</h4>

  <div class="options">
    <select name="option[228]" id="input-option228" class="form-control">
      <option value="0"> --- Please Select --- </option>
      <option value="20">Brown Rice</option>
      <option value="21">White Rice</option>
      <option value="22">Couscous</option>
    </select>

    <div id="BrownRice" data-option-id="20" class="nutritionInfo">
      <span class="caloriesSum">230</span>
      <span class="fatSum">9</span>
      <span class="satfatSum">3</span>
      <span class="carbsSum">3</span>
      <span class="proteinSum">32</span>
      <span class="sodiumSum">170</span>
      <span class="chloesterolSum">90</span>
    </div>

    <div id="WhiteRice" data-option-id="21" class="nutritionInfo">
      <span class="caloriesSum">210</span>
      <span class="fatSum">9</span>
      <span class="satfatSum">3</span>
      <span class="carbsSum">2</span>
      <span class="proteinSum">29</span>
      <span class="sodiumSum">490</span>
      <span class="chloesterolSum">90</span>
    </div> 

    <div id="Couscous" data-option-id="22" class="nutritionInfo">
      <span class="caloriesSum">210</span>
      <span class="fatSum">9</span>
      <span class="satfatSum">3</span>
      <span class="carbsSum">2</span>
      <span class="proteinSum">29</span>
      <span class="sodiumSum">490</span>
      <span class="chloesterolSum">90</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="totals">

    <h4>Totals</h4>

    <ul>
      <li>Calories: <span id="totalCalories"> </span></li>
      <li>Fat: <span id="totalFat"> </span>g</li>
      <li>Sat. Fat: <span id="totalSatFat"> </span>g</li>
      <li>Carbs: <span id="totalCarbs"> </span>g</li>
      <li>Protein: <span id="totalProtein"> </span>g</li>
      <li>Sodium: <span id="totalSodium"> </span>mg</li>
      <li>Cholesterol: <span id="totalChloresterol"> </span>mg</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.options').on('change', 'select', function() {
        var $self = $(this);
        var inputId = $self.val();

        $self.parent('div').find('.active').removeClass('active');
        $self.parent('div')
            .find('[data-option-id='+inputId+']')
            .addClass('active');

        runUpdate();
    });
});

function runUpdate() {
    // get the sum of the elements
    var calories = $(".caloriesSum", '.active').sum();
    var fat = $(".fatSum", '.active').sum();
    var satfat = $(".satfatSum", '.active').sum();
    var carbs = $(".carbsSum", '.active').sum();
    var protein = $(".proteinSum", '.active').sum();
    var sodium = $(".sodiumSum", '.active').sum();
    var chloresterol = $(".chloesterolSum", '.active').sum();

    // update the total
    $("#totalCalories").text(+calories.toString());
    $("#totalFat").text(+fat.toString());
    $("#totalSatFat").text(+satfat.toString());
    $("#totalCarbs").text(+carbs.toString());
    $("#totalProtein").text(+protein.toString());
    $("#totalSodium").text(+sodium.toString());
    $("#totalChloresterol").text(+chloresterol.toString());
}
```

You can see the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/z5u0ajc6/

***UPDATE***

After some comments I made some modifications to mantain the HTML code, so the new solution is below:

**Original HTML**

```
<form action="" method="post" id="nutform" onsubmit="return false;">
  <h4>Select Your Protein</h4>    
  <select name="option[227]" id="input-option227" class="form-control">
    <option value=""> --- Please Select --- </option>
    <option value="17">Herb Turkey</option>
    <option value="18">Moroccan Mince</option>
    <option value="19">Cajun Chicken</option>
  </select>    
  <div>
    <div id="17" class="nutritionInfo">
      <span class="caloriesSum">280</span>
      <span class="fatSum">6</span>
      <span class="satfatSum">0</span>
      <span class="carbsSum">44</span>
      <span class="proteinSum">8</span>
      <span class="sodiumSum">340</span>
      <span class="chloesterolSum">0</span>
    </div>    
    <div id="18" class="nutritionInfo">
      <span class="caloriesSum">290</span>
      <span class="fatSum">6</span>
      <span class="satfatSum">2</span>
      <span class="carbsSum">49</span>
      <span class="proteinSum">9</span>
      <span class="sodiumSum">770</span>
      <span class="chloesterolSum">0</span>
    </div>    
    <div id="19" class="nutritionInfo">
      <span class="caloriesSum">265</span>
      <span class="fatSum">5</span>
      <span class="satfatSum">1</span>
      <span class="carbsSum">33</span>
      <span class="proteinSum">63</span>
      <span class="sodiumSum">12</span>
      <span class="chloesterolSum">6</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h4>Select Your Carbs</h4>    
  <select name="option[228]" id="input-option228" class="form-control">
    <option value=""> --- Please Select --- </option>
    <option value="20">Brown Rice</option>
    <option value="21">White Rice</option>
    <option value="22">Couscous</option>
  </select>
  <div id="20" class="nutritionInfo">
    <span class="caloriesSum">230</span>
    <span class="fatSum">9</span>
    <span class="satfatSum">3</span>
    <span class="carbsSum">3</span>
    <span class="proteinSum">32</span>
    <span class="sodiumSum">170</span>
    <span class="chloesterolSum">90</span>
  </div>    
  <div id="21" class="nutritionInfo">
    <span class="caloriesSum">210</span>
    <span class="fatSum">9</span>
    <span class="satfatSum">3</span>
    <span class="carbsSum">2</span>
    <span class="proteinSum">29</span>
    <span class="sodiumSum">490</span>
    <span class="chloesterolSum">90</span>
  </div>    
  <div id="22" class="nutritionInfo">
    <span class="caloriesSum">210</span>
    <span class="fatSum">9</span>
    <span class="satfatSum">3</span>
    <span class="carbsSum">2</span>
    <span class="proteinSum">29</span>
    <span class="sodiumSum">490</span>
    <span class="chloesterolSum">90</span>
  </div>
  <div id="totals">
    <h4>Totals</h4>
    <ul>
      <li>Calories: <span id="totalCalories"> </span></li>
      <li>Fat: <span id="totalFat"> </span>g</li>
      <li>Sat. Fat: <span id="totalSatFat"> </span>g</li>
      <li>Carbs: <span id="totalCarbs"> </span>g</li>
      <li>Protein: <span id="totalProtein"> </span>g</li>
      <li>Sodium: <span id="totalSodium"> </span>mg</li>
      <li>Cholesterol: <span id="totalChloresterol"> </span>mg</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</form>
```

**New JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#nutform").on("change", "select", function() {
    var changed = $(this).val();
    $(".active").removeClass('active');
    $('#' + changed).addClass('active');
    runUpdate();
  });
});

function runUpdate() {
  var calories = $(".caloriesSum", '.active').sum();
  var fat = $(".fatSum", '.active').sum();
  var satfat = $(".satfatSum", '.active').sum();
  var carbs = $(".carbsSum", '.active').sum();
  var protein = $(".proteinSum", '.active').sum();
  var sodium = $(".sodiumSum", '.active').sum();
  var chloresterol = $(".chloesterolSum", '.active').sum();

  $("#totalCalories").text(+calories.toString());
  $("#totalFat").text(+fat.toString());
  $("#totalSatFat").text(+satfat.toString());
  $("#totalCarbs").text(+carbs.toString());
  $("#totalProtein").text(+protein.toString());
  $("#totalSodium").text(+sodium.toString());
  $("#totalChloresterol").text(+chloresterol.toString());
};
```

> Note that you need the library [jquery.calculation](http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/calculation/jquery.calculation.min.js)!

The new result can be checked here: http://jsfiddle.net/tps07nek/2/

***UPDATE 2***

I think that it is a better solution for you:

**New JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#nutform").on("change", "select", function() {
    $(".active").removeClass('active');
    $.each($("#nutform select"), function(index, select) {
      var changed = $(select).val();      
      $('#' + changed).addClass('active');
    });

    runUpdate();
  });
});

function runUpdate() {
  var calories = $(".caloriesSum", '.active').sum();
  var fat = $(".fatSum", '.active').sum();
  var satfat = $(".satfatSum", '.active').sum();
  var carbs = $(".carbsSum", '.active').sum();
  var protein = $(".proteinSum", '.active').sum();
  var sodium = $(".sodiumSum", '.active').sum();
  var chloresterol = $(".chloesterolSum", '.active').sum();

  $("#totalCalories").text(+calories.toString());
  $("#totalFat").text(+fat.toString());
  $("#totalSatFat").text(+satfat.toString());
  $("#totalCarbs").text(+carbs.toString());
  $("#totalProtein").text(+protein.toString());
  $("#totalSodium").text(+sodium.toString());
  $("#totalChloresterol").text(+chloresterol.toString());
};
```

Comment: I will definitely check that out, thanks. So far on my own I got here: https://jsfiddle.net/1gvsezxx/1/

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't have the select in the same div as the dropdown.

Comment: I have so far got this https://jsfiddle.net/1gvsezxx/5/ and it's working up to the point that it's making the right div "active" however it's giving the error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sum is not a function` any ideas why that's not passing?

Comment: @BN83, Ok. I made some modifications on your JS code. I will edit my answer, but you can check the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/tps07nek/2/

Comment: sorry for the really long delay in coming back to you, life happened! Unfortunately it doesn't work as it only makes one item active, rather than one from each group.

Comment: It may be hacky but I have done the following to get it to work... http://jsfiddle.net/tps07nek/3/

Comment: Do you have this code available in a form where you can add quantity of these food values?

Comment: I checked that page but would like to know if someone knows how to add option for quantity of specific nutrition to the script? If you choose certain type of food, it woudl be nice to have optinos for 100g, 200g, 300g, 400g for example.